# Is it possible to copy or retrieve text from Windows form title or lables on windows form?

Tags: c#

Is there any trick available using which I can copy text from Windows form title or labels on windows form?

Answer (score 1):

We should be oracles to understand the question. For my open mind he's asked about access to text from runtime. For example read the text from window or label under mouse cursor.
For this case you can use `Reflection` for some functions from *Win32* like [GetWindowText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can go to YourForm -> YourForm.Designer.cs -> right click, and see code in solution navigator. This will give you the code of the Form that you've created, having everything that the form has (events, titles, texts, etc, etc).

So, just grab the text from here, you can copy it to another variable in another place and use it, pull it via `: Form` inheritance, or whathever fits more to your needs.

Remember that changes on YourForm.Designer.cs can make that the "View design" command throw errors and end not showing the design of your form, or those changes can be auto-deleted when clicking "View desing", but, it doesn't mean that your form is bad and it won't compile.